# Synchronisation of different "channel" in an asynchronous way

Tags: rabbitmq, asynchronous

I have a scenario where a service needs to update back and forth information from different channels (and each channel should have the same information, e.g inventory of products). 
It all works fine if the process is sequential. Problem is that by adding more and by adding more channels, or with more information, the process get slow.

Creating micro-services for each channel is not a problem; the problem is the communication with each of them and logging errors if there are(once you write it, seems better organized then just planning it).

My question is; is the use of a Message Broker (like RabbitMQ) the right tool to consider in such cases?! or should someone rely purely on communication between services. 
Any practical pattern or use case to follow in such cases?

Comment: I believe your question in is current form is difficult to understand. You may want to expand your first paragraph, explaining a bit more how are you using RabbitMQ exactly and what are you trying to achieve. Given the current description, either your case is so basic that you shouldn't even ask the question in the first place, or what you are trying to achieve is so complex that it simply cannot be done at all with RabbitMQ.

Comment: Thank you for the comment; I did not say I am using RabbitMQ; I was asking if a message brokers such as RabbitMQ would be the recommended tool to use...

Comment: @Armand we don’t do tool recommendations here. They’re explicitly off topic.

Comment: He's not asking to recommend a tool, he's asking about a design using the abstract concept of a message broker, and giving a concrete implementation of that concept as an example.

Comment: Thank you @KarlBielefeldt. You are right, I am not asking for a tool recommendation; I am asking if the message broker can be used in a domain inventory pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly what a message broker buys you is the ability to publish to a topic without having to keep track of the subscribers. Message brokers don't magically speed you up. In fact, they add some queuing latency. You still have to change your services to process messages asynchronously, and that change can be done without adding a message broker.

Even if you do add a message broker, changing your current code to be more asynchronous first would be a recommended incremental migration step. That way you can clearly separate what being async buys you from what the message broker buys you.